# Kendo Angular DataGrid - Switch between multiple kendoGridDetailTemplates

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a Kendo DataGrid and I want to reuse it with multiple different kendoGridDetailTemplate

The kendo detail grid goes something like the following

```
 <ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem >
    <div>{{dataItem.Name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

I have added a reference name 'kendodetails' to this template.

```
 <ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem #kendodetails>
    <div>{{dataItem.Name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

and am using

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="kendodetails;context={dataItem: dataItem}">
</ng-container>
```

to make a call to the template which I moved outside the

```
<kendo-grid></kendo-grid>
```

The problem is the context to the dataItem isn't passed properly and it throws the follwing error.

> Property 'Name' of 'undefined' not found

Also can I move the template into a different html file if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `let-dataItem` instead of `let-dataItem="dataItem"` in your template declaration, you need to set `dataItem` as the default value.

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="kendodetails;context={$implicit: dataItem}">
</ng-container>
```

#### Generally

You can access each `field` in the `context`-object via `let-<variable>="<field>"` declarations.
But you can only access the default (`$implicit`) one via `let-<variable>`.